# Recover deleted files after git push --force in github

Tags: git, github, git-bash

accidentally I push code in GitHub by --force flag. After pushed the code, I got an url it looks like this,

```
compare/3b97dc6ae39ff9416863cbcdfa0a65dd315db7cd..b234e255fc5462a7c46e48ebf720b4f97f54480d?diff=split
```

now I want to revert back to `3b97dc6ae39ff9416863cbcdfa0a65dd315db7cd` this commit. But I'm not able to move. I tried with this,

```
git reset --hard 3b97dc6ae39ff9416863cbcdfa0a65dd315db7cd

fatal: Could not parse object '3b97dc6ae39ff9416863cbcdfa0a65dd315db7cd'.
```

How could I revert back to this commit ? Can anyone please help to do that? TIA

Comment: Are there any other clones of the repository that haven't incorporated the change yet?

Comment: Does the object exist in `git reflog`?

Comment: no there have no repo cloned, and git reflog does have any commits which are gone after force push @choroba

Comment: Normally, commits stay in the reflog after a force push.

Comment: Do you understand what the reflog is? Not log — reflog.

Comment: The problem is your local repo doesn't have that commit yet. You need to fetch it, and, now depending on the state of the repo, a default `git fetch` *might* work, but YoichiNakyama's answer below will *definitely* work.

Comment: Note, in the question, twice you use the word "revert" where, since we're talking about Git, it's obvious you mean "reset" instead.  The word "revert" in Git has a slightly different meaning than in English. In Git it basically means, make a new commit that undoes all of the changes in another commit. (You use revert instead of reset when you don't want to rewrite history.)

Comment: yes, basically I needed to revert back to the commit before force push, and there are some commits that are gone after force push. So badly I need to back to my previous state. So finally I got all my changes and work from my friend who actually forked the project. Thanks for your response. In the meantime, I learn a lot about git also. @TTT

Answer (score 2):

Try `git fetch origin 3b97dc6ae39ff9416863cbcdfa0a65dd315db7cd` before `git reset`.